# php nested while loop in smarty using foreach

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I have the following PHP code.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE mb_status = 'enabled'");
$stmt-> execute();

$mbData = array();
while($f = $stmt->fetch()){
  $mbData[] = $f;
  $mbsId = $f['mb_id'];

  $stmtUpg = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM upgrade_validities WHERE upval_membership = :mbs");
  $stmtUpg-> bindValue(':mbs', $mbsId);
  $stmtUpg-> execute();

  $upgVal = array();
  while($uf = $stmtUpg->fetch()){
    $upgVal[] = $uf;
  }
}
$smarty->assign('mbData', $mbData);
$smarty->assign('upgVal', $upgVal);
```

Smarty code using foreach

```
{foreach from=$mbData key=k item=b}
  {$b.mb_name}
  <!-- Listing Item -->
  {foreach from=$upgVal key=k item=a}
      <h3>Member Id: {$a.upval_id}</h3> // doesn't get displayed
  {/foreach}
  <!-- Listing Item / End -->
{/foreach}
```

Here, the Member Id in the nested foreach loop isn't getting displayed. I don't know what is the error I am making.

Comment: Instead of using '{$a.upval_id}' try using '{$a["upval_id"]}'.

Comment: @CharlesEF before you recommend me that, are you familier enough with smarty? Plus, it didn't work. Also, please note that if the nested bit of for loop would seem to work, then even if I do not get the value to `{$a.upval_id}`, I will still get `Member Id:` as text appearing for number of counts. So here, it seems maybe my while loop logic has some issues.

Comment: It's usually a better approach to run database query inside a loop. In this case you can easily run one query to get the info you need.

Comment: @RedStar Entertainment  Oh, sorry I didn't realize I was looking at smarty code.  I guess I confused it with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE mb_status = 'enabled'");
$stmt-> execute();

$mbData = array();
while($f = $stmt->fetch()){
  $mbData[] = $f;
  $mbsId = $f['mb_id'];

  $stmtUpg = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM upgrade_validities WHERE upval_membership = :mbs");
  $stmtUpg-> bindValue(':mbs', $mbsId);
  $stmtUpg-> execute();

  // change begin
  $upgValTemp = array();
  while($uf = $stmtUpg->fetch()){
    $upgValTemp[] = $uf;
  }
  $upgVal[$mbsId] = $upgValTemp;

}
$smarty->assign('mbData', $mbData);
$smarty->assign('upgVal', $upgVal);
```

SMARTY:

```
{foreach from=$mbData key=k item=b}
  {$b.mb_name}
  <!-- Listing Item -->
  {foreach from=$upgVal[$b.mb_id] key=k item=a} {* changed here *}
      <h3>Member Id: {$a.upval_id}</h3>
  {/foreach}
  <!-- Listing Item / End -->
{/foreach}
```

Comment: you welcome :) would me nice if you mark as accepted answer :)